# Excel if or query on multiple options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to either pass or fail a set of tests based on different pass/fail/blocked criteria.

Here's my table:
     [image]

I would like to add a Pass/Fail or Blocked result in the 'result goes here' cell, so I guess i'll need multiple if/or statements.

For a pass outcome, the criteria is that 'Critical fail' and 'Blocked' are =0, and 'Passed' is > 0.

For a fail result Critical fail must be > 0 (regardless of other values)

For a blocked result Blocked must be > 0 (regardless of other values)

So I am guessing in need an if statement with a couple of OR statements and the 'Passed' query has an AND query within itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What excel version go you have?

Comment: We call these kinds of questions asking for people to write code for you "homework help". For homework help to be considered [ON TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you have to ***include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you need to use several IF statements:

```
IF(B5>0,"Blocked",IF(B3>0,"Critical",IF(AND(B3=0,B5=0,B1>0),"Critical Fail",NA())))
```

Where

- B1 > "passed" value
- B3 > "critical fail" value
- B5 > "blocked" value

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks this got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Excel version 2016+ and this layout:

[image]

```
=IFS(D5>0,"Critical fail outcome",D7>0,"Failed outcome",Y(D5=0,D7=0,D3>0),"Pass outcome",True,"")
```

Remarks: The last True and "" are the default values if none of the previous statements return true